# Catching email delivery errors

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I have a Google Apps spreadsheet that is filled by user-submitted forms. I'm trying to write a script that verifies that the Email field filled by the users is valid. I'm using `MailApp` to send a confirmation email and catching errors, like this:

```
try {
  MailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, message, {'htmlBody':htmlMessage, 'noReply':true});
  Logger.log("Sending email to " + address);
 } catch(e) {
  return "Failed: Invalid address";
 }
```

This works fine for immediate errors (null or malformed addresses), but not for non-existing email addresses. To catch those, until now I used the following code to wait 5 seconds and then check the inbox for Mail Delivery Notification emails:

```
Utilities.sleep(5000);
var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread subject:\"delivery status notification\" " + address);
if (threads.length > 0) {
  return "Failed: Delivery failed. " + threads[0].getPermalink();
}
```

This worked fine last year when I used it last, but trying now, I don't get the mail delivery notifications messages anymore when sending mail via script - apparently Google changed something, and now only manually sent messages receive the notification.

So given that my previous method has stopped working, does anyone have any idea of an alternative, automated method to verify the emails work?

Comment: Thanks for pinpointing this, I didn't even noticed it... one can indeed use any surrealist mail address without any reaction from MailApp or gmailApp... strange (+1)  more strange is that I don't get error message when sent from gmail online neither, at least not until now (just tested it today)

Comment: I do seem to get errors when sending manually, but not immediately. It takes 10-15 seconds.

Comment: My today's tests didn't return any error, the test address was sssss@gtest.com, I guess this one was "wrong enough" :-) I'll keep an eye on this.In the mean time I see no way to monitor the errors... I'll be of no help on this one. good luck.

Comment: Just came across this with the same result. Sending the email from GAS doesn't catch an error, I just get the bounceback in my inbox.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - are you still experiencing this problem? Just tested out `MailApp.sendEmail` on my G Suite account (given that you're using `noReply`) and I did get an email with sub **Delivery Status Notification (Failure)** from **mailer-daemon@googlemail.com** - looks like its working again now?